# [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, nullreferenceexception

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Wictor.Office365.MsOnlineClaimsHelper.getCookieContainer() +128
   Wictor.Office365.MsOnlineClaimsHelper.clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest(Object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e) +33
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest() +382
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery() +16
   Webapplicatie.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +334
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +70
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3177
```

is the message I'm getting when I deploy my website online.

Locally everything is running fine, even when I copy all project files to another computer everything shows fine.

However, when I publish the site to the IIS server it shows the error as displayed above.

Are the any settings which I could be missing?
I doubt this is a coding issue as everything works perfectly on the `localhost`

code in Default.aspx.cs:

```
  MsOnlineClaimsHelper claimsHelper = new MsOnlineClaimsHelper(sharepointsiteUrl, username, password);
            using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(sharepointsiteUrl))
            {
                context.ExecutingWebRequest += claimsHelper.clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest;

                context.Load(context.Web);

                context.ExecuteQuery();

                Lebel.Text = "Succesfully logged in as " + username + " on " + context.Web.Title;
            }"
```

Additional code for MsOnlineClaimsHelper

```
// Method used to add cookies to CSOM
    public void clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest(object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e) {
        e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.CookieContainer = getCookieContainer();
        //e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.UserAgent = userAgent;
    }

    // Creates or loads cached cookie container
    CookieContainer getCookieContainer() {
        if (_cachedCookieContainer == null || DateTime.Now > _expires) {

            // Get the SAML tokens from SPO STS (via MSO STS) using fed auth passive approach
            MsoCookies cookies = getSamlToken();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookies.FedAuth)) {

                // Create cookie collection with the SAML token                    
                _expires = cookies.Expires;
                CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();

                // Set the FedAuth cookie
                Cookie samlAuth = new Cookie("FedAuth", cookies.FedAuth) {
                    Expires = cookies.Expires,
                    Path = "/",
                    Secure = cookies.Host.Scheme == "https",
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    Domain = cookies.Host.Host
                };
                cc.Add(samlAuth);


                if (_useRtfa) {
                    // Set the rtFA (sign-out) cookie, added march 2011
                    Cookie rtFa = new Cookie("rtFA", cookies.rtFa) {
                        Expires = cookies.Expires,
                        Path = "/",
                        Secure = cookies.Host.Scheme == "https",
                        HttpOnly = true,
                        Domain = cookies.Host.Host
                    };
                    cc.Add(rtFa);
                }
                _cachedCookieContainer = cc;
                return cc;
            }
            return null;
        }
        return _cachedCookieContainer;
    }

    public CookieContainer CookieContainer {
        get {
            if (_cachedCookieContainer == null || DateTime.Now > _expires) {
                return getCookieContainer();
            }
            return _cachedCookieContainer;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's a bit of a code here, would be useful to tell us _where_ you're getting this error.

Comment: @GrantThomas see first post, the exact error is on top. thanks in advance

Comment: OKay, well that tells you where the error is happening exactly; it's easier for you because you have the source in the editor + line counts etc. but something in the `getCookieContainer` is `null` and you're trying to do something with it. Can `getSamlToken();` return `null`? If so then accessing `cookies.FedAuth` will break - use that as an example and check things aren't nothing (i.e. `if (something != null)`.

Comment: @GrantThomas getSamlToken() throws this exception `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft.EntityModel.dll was not added on the server on publish.
I've put this .dll manually on the server and now it works.

Thanks for your help GrantThomas.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually Microsoft.IdentityModel reference with path:

> C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Windows Identity
>   Foundation\v3.5\Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll

if you have a VS installed